How to select all rows of a lazy grid programmatically?
I am using vaadin flow grid with multiple selection mode, I have added a dataprovider to this grid. I want to select all rows on a button click. Rows are being selected but UI is not being refreshed even after refreshing the dataprovider.
checkboxes and rows color not showing selected) !
How to solve this ?
Grid rows selected and checkboxes must be shown checked.

please show your code, especially your button click listener that selects all items.

Sounds like object identity problem ... Are you using Lombok's Data annotation?

Yes, I am using lombok, but each object has unique field.
